# how to find the number of maximum available threads in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Not sure what is the best way to find the number of maximum available threads of my GPU.
I have the following code:

```
int deviceCount, device;
int gpuDeviceCount = 0;
struct cudaDeviceProp properties;
cudaError_t cudaResultCode = cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
if (cudaResultCode != cudaSuccess)
    deviceCount = 0;
/* machines with no GPUs can still report one emulation device */
for (device = 0; device < deviceCount; ++device) {
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&properties, device);
    if (properties.major != 9999) /* 9999 means emulation only */
    if (device==0)
    {
            printf("multiProcessorCount %d\n",properties.multiProcessorCount);
            printf("maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor %d\n",properties.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor);
    }
}
```

which returns:

```
multiProcessorCount 14
maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor 1536
```

It turns out the total number is 14*1536=21504. I got a feeling it is too small (I have a Tesla M2070).

Comment: The maximum number of threads per multiprocessor is the upper limit to how many threads can be "in flight" at the same time. Other limiting factors will normally limit the number further. This value does not affect how many threads can be launched at the same time and it is not very useful for finding out the number of threads needed for optimal performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your way of checking is correct.
you can check the NVIDIA cuda SDK samples, "Device query" sample in SDK defines it well